# Multiple Matches in regex and store or print it

Tags: javascript, regex

My code does some regex match on search text and returns only the 1st matched value .

I would like to have other's too and want to store or print them.

Currently I do.

```
var regexg = new RegExp(regex,"g");
return regexg.exec(text)[1];
```

This only returns the first matched text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exec in a loop like this:

```
var regexg = new RegExp(regex,"g"),
    matches = [];
while (match = regexg.exec(text)) matches.push(match[1]);

// print all matches
console.log(matches);
```